# Cannot install AMD GPU driver correctly on a hybrid laptop

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, fglrx, proprietary-drivers, amd-graphics

I was installing AMD gpu driver but the default display driver (Gallium 0.4 llvmpipe) wont get replaced. Btw, My laptop has both Intel and AMD gpu. The system uses Intel gpu by default with the driver Gallium 0.4.

Here's my GPUs:

```
root@kali:/# lspci -v | grep -i 'VGA\|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Grap
ichs Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
03:00.0 Display controller: Advance Mirco Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 6660
```

Here's the link I followed to install the driver: [Install AMD ATI proprietary fglrx driver in Kali Linux 1.0.6](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/03/05/install-amd-ati-proprietary-fglrx-driver-kali-linux-1-0-6/)

I was able to install all the prerequisites/dependencies and the driver without any error and I was able to run `aticonfig --initial` to create an `xorg.conf` file. I also added the  line `radeon.modeset=0` to `grub.cfg`

After the installation, I run `fglrxinfo` and it returned
`display: :0.0 screen: 0`
`OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.`
`OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x209)`
`OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 8.0.5)`

I was curious that I'm not running Kali Linux on VM (I installed it on my laptop). I rebooted my laptop, all was working fine until I got stuck on a `all black with a non-blinking cursor`. I launched a console via `ctrl+alt+f1` and purge all `fglrx`. Deleted the `xorg.conf` and removed the `radeon.modeset=0` to the `grub.cfg`.

I was wondering where did I go wrong or there's no way to install these drivers on my laptop?

Btw, my AMD GPU is `AMD RADEON HD 8670M` and my Intel one is `Intel HD Graphics 4400`. I really need the AMD GPU for `pyrit`.

Comment: I had the same problem last week. EXACTLY the same. I solved it by enabling legacy and UEFI in my BIOS boot settings. Good luck!